# Restore the full contents of conflicting files during a merge to either "ours" or "theirs"

Tags: git

I am doing a large automatic code reformat of a codebase for linting purposes, but there are several other developers working concurrently. This will of course cause many conflicts.

I created a branch containing the state of the world immediately prior to my lint run called `prelint`, then merged the formatted code into `main`.

My initial attempt to resolve this easily was something like the following (lets assume this is a clean checkout from origin):

```
git checkout conflicted-branch
git pull origin prelint # code conflicts can be resolved here
git pull origin main -X ours # take the logical changes from the conflicted-branch
npm run lint # rerun the linter on the logical changes
```

However, this badly mangles the code as only the conflicting *lines* are taken. Because I *know* that my linter is only making formatting changes, what I would like is a full file replace of any conflicting file back to its premerge state, as I can then rerun the linter with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ultimately landed on works, but is imperfect:

```
git checkout conflicted-branch
git pull origin prelint # resolve any logical conflicts here
git pull origin dev # resolve *only* file moves/deletions. Leave code conflicts unresolved
# run the next command with the merge still active
currentbranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | awk '{system("git restore --source origin/'$currentbranch' -- ../" $0)}'
# stage all files and commit the fixed merge. Your files are now in the state they were in on your branch before linting
npm run lint # rerun the linter on the logical changes in the conflicted branch
```

The critical line there is

```
currentbranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | awk '{system("git restore --source origin/'$currentbranch' -- ../" $0)}'
```

This will replace the full contents of any conflicted files in your current merge on whatever branch you are currently on (and thus is implicitly replacing "ours")

This answer could be improved in the following ways, if someone is feeling enterprising:

1. This will fail for files that were deleted/moved/renamed. Those conflicts need to be manually resolved before running. It would be nice if they could just be accepted, but I didn't know how to differentiate them in `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U` .
2. It would be nice if there were an easy way to pass the equivalent of the merge strategy flag for "ours" vs "theirs", as sometimes it would be useful to do this in the opposite direction
3. It would be nice if the command would more cleanly handle logical conflicts that appear in the step before (i.e. the `git pull origin prelint` stage)